# Unable to find DB2 connector in Anypoint Studio

Tags: db2, mule, esb, mule-studio

I am trying to install the DB2 connector in Mule Studio. I am using Anypoint Studio October 2014 Release. I tried following the instructions given here: http://www.mulesoft.org/connectors/db2-connector-3.4.0%3B3.5.0-Everest#install but am unable to find the connector in any of the available sites. How do I install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use Database building block and Generic Database Configuration with the DB2 JDBC Connector. Here you can find the DB2 JDBC Connector: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

1. Download the DB2 JDBC Connector
2. Add the DB2 JDBC Connector (.Jar) to your project
3. Right Click in your project > Build Path > Add external Archive
4. Add a Database Building Block to your flow and use a generic database configuration

Comment: Also, you can try using the DB2 Connectors:

https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/db2-integration-connector

https://www.mulesoft.org/connectors/db2-connector-3.4.0%3B3.5.0-Everest

Answer (score 0):

The Database connector is pre-installed in Studio for Mule 3.5 and above.
For Mule 3.4 and below, use the JDBC Connector.

Here you can find the DB2 JDBC Connector: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

Download the DB2 JDBC Connector
Add the DB2 JDBC Connector (.Jar) to your project
Right Click in your project > Build Path > Add external Archive
Add a Database Building Block to your flow and use a generic database configuration