# How do I allow access to my Mule flow only for a particular set of IP addresses?

Tags: http, mule, ip-address

I have a Mule application with a HTTP endpoint. I wish to only allow requests coming from a particular set of IP addresses to access the flow. How do I restrict it? Which filter should I use? I am saving the IP addresses in a file inside the application. If a custom filter is used, how should it be written?

Comment: A similar question has been asked before, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599111/use-groovy-expression-for-limited-ip-in-mule) and see if that's of any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Mule EE, the Anypoint Filter Processor can be used to filter inbound requests dependant on the IP address.

> Generally positioned immediately after an inbound connector in a Mule
>   flow, the Anypoint Filter Processor evaluates two message properties,
>   then rejects the message if the values fall outside of its configured
>   parameters. The properties that are evaluated are:
>
> - **IP address** – If the IP address of a message falls outside the filter’s
>     configured IP address range, Mule does not process the message (see
>     image below).
> - **Creation timestamps** — Where the message’s creation date
>     and time fall outside the filter’s configured acceptable lifespan
>     (i.e. the message is older than expected), Mule does not process the
>     message (see image below).

The full documentation can be found [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Anypoint+Filter+Processor).

Alternatively, if you are using CE, the link in my comment on the original question may help.

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me how to set the `${allowed}` variable in answer there? Also could you answer my other two questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607661/how-to-use-mules-xml-to-object-transformer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605651/unable-to-find-db2-connector-in-anypoint-studio. I am a complete newbie in Mule and I really require help using this.

Comment: ${allowed} is the IP address or list of IP Addresses separated by comma